# AWS ECS Fargate port Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have ECS cluster.In that there are two task definitions and each task definition have only one container.We are using ECS fargate model here with networking type as awsvpc.

Task Definition 1: Query-Conatiner
Task Definition 2: Send-Conatiner

Now there are 2 services for each of the two task definitions above.

Query-Conatiner and Send-Conatiners both are mapped to port 8080 of host.

Wont there be any conflict as both ports are mapped to 8080 ?

Answer (score 4):

When using awsvpc, each container gets assigned a different Elastic Network Interfaces (ENI), so each container will have a different IP, hence, no port conflict (e.g. Query-Container is at 10.0.0.1:8080, Send-Container is at 10.0.0.2:8080).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html

Comment: Is this IP different than the host IP(EC2) on which the container is running ?

Comment: Yes, it a different network interface. Again, this is only when using awsvpc networking mode. And since you are running fargate, there is no visible host EC2 instance for you anyway.

Comment: Yes there is no visibility of EC2 in fargate. But just wondering if tomorrow i want to run 4 replicas of task 1 for autoscaling then in backend if it runs couple of task on same EC2 then also same results ?

Comment: When using Fargate you don't need to worry about anything EC2 related, but in general, even if you use awsvpc within EC2-backed ECS, each container receives a different ENI, and they are all different than the ENI of host instance.

Comment: So in case for ECS-EC2 if i want application load balancer then in target group i have to add ENI IP as instance?

Answer (score 1):

Each ECS Task has different IP. So no port conflicts.